# Draw a huge GeoJSON with leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm aiming to represent a huge geojson file (around 250Mb) using leaflet, therefore, I need to render my data before displaying it. 
I want to only load data that is in the bounds of my leaflet frame. Also, I want, as long as the map load the quality of the polygon bounderies increases. I think the same process is used in loading tiles.

Comment: What is your server stack? Probably you can try to use [VectorTiles](https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles) or [Tiled GeoJSON](https://django-geojson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#tiled-geojson-layer-view)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From " I need to render my data before displaying it" I assume that you do not need to draw GeoJSON as vector. In such a case you may publish your data using GeoServer etc as wms. This will take load from client to the server in cost of incresed bandwidth usage in your server.

In case you need to render map on client side you may check [GeoServer Vector Tiles](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html) and [Leaflet vector tiles](https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile)

Comment: Actually, I want to make some modifications on the polygons that will be displayed, like for example Merge two polygons. Therefore I don't think tiles is what I'm looking for.